# One Module fields use in other module

Tags: odoo

I am trying to use some fields of "Job Positions" in "Opportunities" and we can say it as a merger fields.  but i am unable to do this task . i have no knowledge about Python language.

I have created a user defined fields and use it in opportunities by XML coding by developer options . I know that it is easy because user defined fields has "crm.lead" named module which is same in opportunities.

but now When i want to use this fields in "hr.job" then it give me error "fields not found" . i know that this fields is not in current module and it is part of "crm.lead" not "hr.job".

Is it possible to use one module fields in another module?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do so. First you have to create an object for that and then browse the record and fetch the value of the field which you want. 

For example create one method and then browse the crm.lead record:

```
crm_obj = self.pool.get('crm.lead')
crm_brw = crm_obj.browse(cr, uid, crm_rec_id, context=context)
print "my field value::  ", crm_brw.your_field
```

Here, "crm_rec_id" is the id of the record of crm.lead object

There are lots of examples given in addons.

Comment: it is not giving me any message in browser . please tell me how can i display value in a text-field of opportunities . thank you expert

Comment: hi , is it possible in xml file . such as we'll edit to xml file and field display of other module in current module

Comment: field must be of same class. You can use any field of 'crm.lead' in any module.
You can not use other object's field in xml view file.
For example: you can not add any field of 'hr.job' in view of 'hr.crm'

Comment: Thank you 4 your reply,  please sir may you provide me any example ?

Comment: There are lots of examples in addons. You can refer account, sale, stock, etc modules.

Comment: thank,  i've three files hr.py , crm_lead.py, crm_lead_view.xml files. i think , i need update it . but i have no knowledge of python . so i am unable . may you provide me any code ? i used updated by "Heroic" user name answer but not get any fields . please sir help me. it is very urgent 4 me thank you

Answer (score 1):

yes you can it done by _inherits.
for eg.
hr_job in hr module .

```
class hr_job(osv.osv):
    _name = "hr.job"
    _description = "job position"
        _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('job name', size=64)

      }
```

crm_lead in crm module.

```
class crm_lead(osv.osv):
    _name = "crm.lead"
   _inherits = {'hr.job': 'job_id'}
    _description = "Lead/Opportunity"
        _columns = {
        'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner')

      }
```

in xml file of crm create form view.

```
<record id="crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
             <field name="name"/> # job name from hr_job
             <field name="partner_id"/> # partner_id from crm.lead
           </form>
       </field>
 </record>
```

don't forget add dependency.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  In crm_lead.py file , i am unable to find " class crm_lead(osv.osv): " it . i find " class crm_lead(crm_case, osv.osv): " . do i need to use it ? if yes,  this class already use " _inherit = ['mail.thread','res.partner.address']"  . how may i use to other _inherit.  please check it sir . thank you

Comment: hi sir. i have used hr.py , crm_lead.py, crm_lead_view.xml files. but not got any fields. please sir help me . thank you 4 your kindly response

Comment: _inherit(name of the parent business object
) and _inherits(for multiple / instance inheritance mechanism: dictionary mapping the _name of the parent business objects
to the names of the corresponding foreign key fields to use
) are two different thing in openerp and you can use both on same object , and you need to add dependency between two module in  openerp if you edit in xml you have to update that module also don't forget it.

Comment: please read openerp documentation will help you more http://doc.openerp.com/memento/

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I am highly obliged. I got the logic, it seems it is going to work. BUT can't figure it out that how will I add dependency. Will be greatful if you come up with an example. THANKS

Comment: Dependency means List of modules on which this module depends. The base module must almost always be in the dependencies because some necessary data for the views, reports, ... are in the base module if crm is depend on hr then you have to add dependency in __openerp__.py file that contain python dictionary

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20172/discussion-between-rahul-rawat-and-heroic)

Comment: for __openerp__.py please read http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_4_module_development/module_descriptor.html

Comment: hi, i saw that crm.lead is not depand on hr .  so i think , i may not use to openerp.py .  and i updated my  hr.py , crm_lead.py, crm_lead_view.xml files by your kindly code.  then i restart my server . but not get any fields of job in opportunities . please sir , may i mail my three files you by mail . if you agree. please sir it is urgent thank you