# How use a fields of module A in module B

Tags: odoo

i have two module opportunities and job positions .
i am trying to use only one field of "job positions" name Employees  in "opportunities" module.

i am new in openerp and have no knowledge about python . so i am using developer option of openerp . i am attaching my both module file .

Is there any attribute of fields or other so my field will use the value of other module values like as :-

crm.lead xml file:-

```
<field name="name" module="hr.job" />
```

here module is not using value of "hr.job" and using of "crm.lead" value.
if i used other name it give me "not field found" error.

please expert help me 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem pretty confused. What you've attached are **view files** for your modules, for instance one of them is the form view for object named hr.job. This is not as you call it "module files".

What you need to do is create a **many2one** (or **many2many**) field from the referenced object you want to the target object you need, meaning adding a field to whatever class's columns you need in the corresponding **py file** and not view. A very simple example for a class named opportunity_opportunity:

```
class opportunity_opportunity (osv.osv):  
        _name = "opportunity.opportunity"  
        _columns = {  
                'name' : fields.char('Name', size=64),  
                'employee_id': fields.many2one('job.position','name')  
                 }  
opportunity_opportunity()
```

you can later add it in the opportunity_view.xml file as any other field:

`<field name="employee_id" string="Employee"/>`

More importantly, I think you need to seriously first read and understand the developer book: [OpenERP 6.1 Developer Book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/index.html)

**EDIT:** I just noticed you had already posted the same question yesterday here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579178/one-module-fields-use-in-other-module), this is very frowned upon in stackoverflow. Please take your time to read the openerp documentation before posting questions.

Comment: thank you , i am new in openerp and phython . so i was a bit confuse . and now learning it. thank you for your help.

Comment: glad i could help Rahul. be sure to check this as an accepted answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: hi , This code is very useful 4 me. i've just created a field by setting menu. field've :- x_country, many2one,crm.lead, object-link( Employee). and used <field name="x_emp"/> in opportunities. This is going well and give me a "employee" with dropdown menu 4 select employee names.   BUT WHEN I AM DOING FOR "TEXT" , I M UNABLE TO SELECT OBJECT-LINK . I AM TRYING TO CREATE A PARTICULAR TEXT LINK. SUCH AS JOB FILED VALUE SHOULD BE DISPLAY IN OPPORTUNITIES CUSTOM FIELDS. please give me kindly suggestion. thank you